# LoadIncrementalHFiles not working for Hbase Bulk Load. Scan returns 0 rows

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hbase

I am using spark to import oracle table into Hbase. I used bulk import option to generate hfiles in hdfs staging directory. Once I run LoadIncrementalHFiles to load data into hbase table.

```
hBaseContext.bulkLoad(rdds, TableName.valueOf("pink"), new BulkLoadFunction1(), "/solidk", new HashMap<byte[], FamilyHFileWriteOptions>(), false, HConstants.DEFAULT_MAX_FILE_SIZE);
```

hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles -Dcreate.table=yes /solidk pink

where /solidk is my staging directory and pink is table name. 
I can see table being created and hfiles being moved into hbase directory but scan returns 0 rows found. Anyone got some idea?

Comment: seems like you maybe using a different user to open hbase shell and scan, can you try your standard hbase/ hdfs user

Comment: Its same user across all services.